# Trigger Update with related tables in 2 different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger to update a table from `db1` to a table in `db2`

The relationship like this;

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_PERSONAS] 
ON [dbo].[Personas]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
     UPDATE [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee]
     SET
        [EmployeeCode] = [Numero_Documento],
        [EmployeeName] = [Nombres],
        [EnglishName] = [Apellidos],
        [CardNo] = [Codigo],
        [pin] = 1234,
        [EmpEnable] = [Estado],
        [Sex] = 'false',
        [Birthday] = CAST(0x0000890400000000 AS DATETIME),
        [Deleted] = 0,
        [Leave] = 0,
        [BeKQ] = 1,
        [MapVisible] = 1,
        [ShowCardNo] = 1,
        [RegDate] = [Fecha_Hora],
        [EndDate] = [FechaVence],
        [Status] = [Estado],
        [DeptID] = [Tipo],
        [JobID] = [Id_Centro_Costos],
        [TimeStamp] = GETDATE()
     FROM 
        [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee]
     INNER JOIN 
        [ControlSuite].[dbo].[Personas] ON [ControlSuite].[dbo].[Personas].[Id_Persona] = [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee].[EmployeeID]
     WHERE 
        [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee].[EmployeeID] = updated.[Personas].[Id_Persona];
 END;
```

but I get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "updated.Personas.Id_Persona" could not be bound

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UPDATED table only INSERTED and DELETED.

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_PERSONAS] ON [dbo].[Personas]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
 BEGIN

     UPDATE [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee]
       SET
           [EmployeeCode] = [Numero_Documento],
           [EmployeeName] = [Nombres],
           [EnglishName] = [Apellidos],
           [CardNo] = [Codigo],
           [pin] = 1234,
           [EmpEnable] = [Estado],
           [Sex] = 'false',
           [Birthday] = CAST(0x0000890400000000 AS DATETIME),
           [Deleted] = 0,
           [Leave] = 0,
           [BeKQ] = 1,
           [MapVisible] = 1,
           [ShowCardNo] = 1,
           [RegDate] = [Fecha_Hora],
           [EndDate] = [FechaVence],
        [Status]=[Estado],
        [DeptID]=[Tipo],
        [JobID]=[Id_Centro_Costos],
           [TimeStamp] = GETDATE()
     FROM [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee]
          INNER JOIN [ControlSuite].[dbo].[Personas] ON [ControlSuite].[dbo].[Personas].[Id_Persona] = [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee].[EmployeeID]
     WHERE [AXData].[dbo].[TEmployee].[EmployeeID] IN ( SELECT i.[Id_Persona] FROM  inserted AS i INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON i.[Id_Persona] = d.[Id_Persona]) ;
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo tables in a SQL Server trigger context are called

- `Deleted` : contains rows that have been deleted (in a `DELETE` trigger), or the *old values* of rows in an `UPDATE` trigger
- `Inserted` : contains rows that have been inserted (in an `INSERT` trigger), or the *new values* of rows in an `UPDATE` trigger

There is no `updated` pseudo table